# Django app cannot find environment varibles

Tags: python, linux, django, bash, amazon-web-services

I posted a question a little bit similar to this earlier on but couldn't find the answers I was looking for, so after some research I have refined it somewhat.

I have written a Django app to be deployed with AWS Elastic Beanstalk which uses an RDS database. My Elastic Beanstalk environment has several environment variables used to access the database, which are accessed in my settings.py file as follows:

```
'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
```

This works fine with the deployed version of the app, but it is still under development so would be very useful to access these variables in my local linux environment. I wrote a bash script that exports the variables and I can test that this works using "echo $", which returns the right value.

However when I try and run the app locally, I get a KeyError (specifically "KeyError: 'RDS_DB_NAME'") so it seems as if the Django app cannot pick up environment variables which I have previously declared.

I'm a bit stumped - any ideas or further questions very welcome!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use [django-environ](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ)

With it you can just create .env file variable you need. Also it will allow ( but don't force to) you to set whole db configuration ( and other too like cache,etc) as url like this:

```
DATABASE_URL=psql://urser:un-githubbedpassword@127.0.0.1:8458/database
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could handle this situation is by defining a condition on when to use the environment variables and when to use the local (hardcoded) variables.

The following code snippet is taken from [RealPython](https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/) article on how to deploy a Django app on AWS:

```
if 'RDS_DB_NAME' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'name',
            'USER': 'user',
            'PASSWORD': 'pass',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is very useful, thank you! I would, however, prefer to use environment variables if possible because I plan on eventually deploying the finished project to Github, and would rather not publish access to my database!

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu go to your home directory and open file `.bashrc`.

add the following line at the end of this file add this:

```
export RDS_DB_NAME='<your_local_db_name>'
```

close terminal and reopen. Run django server and done.

EDIT:

try

`'NAME': os.environ.get('RDS_DB_NAME', ''),`

instead of

```
'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to help. I still get the same key error.

Comment: did you closed all your open terminal tabs and re-ran the server in new terminal?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately no change.

Comment: Please check edit. Also you need to check if variable RDS_DB_NAME is present in your environment variables or not